# Infinite Loading using a HTML Partial

Tags: javascript

Basically, I'm trying to create an infinite loading page on the product listing using a load more and firing a click event on the pagination.

My issue is that I can load the next page into the HTML but it is pulling in the whole HTML file and not just the products.

I'm trying to use a HTML partial to append the next page products into the current div.

**This is my JS currently.**

```
$(".page-next a").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
       var partial = "@Html.Partial('_ProductWithHover')";
       var url = $(this).data('url');
       $.ajax({url: url,method: 'GET',dataType: 'html', success: function (data) {
       $('#js-infinite-scroll-page').append(partial);
        }
     });
});
```

Not sure if I should include my partial the way I have, so any feedback or advice on how to get this working would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an asynchronous behaviour you probably should change your backend api to respond with the necessary json, and construct the dom on the client side. That is way easier. Also, I don't exactly see, how do you provide information to your backend service about the current state of the infinite loading.

So infinite loading is a glorified pagination, it works like this:

You render some number of elements initially, and when you scroll enough, you trigger a request to load the next n elements, and you append them to your list. For this to work, you have to let the backend know where you stand, and after that it can return the next n elements.